# Uso de mayúsculas en nombres de negocios

Tags: ortografía, nombres-propios, uso-de-mayúsculas

Digamos que tenemos un negocio llamado *La Casa del Pan*.

¿Cuál sería la forma adecuada de escribir las mayúsculas?

> Bienvenido a la casa del pan
>
> Bienvenido a La casa del pan
>
> Bienvenido a La Casa del Pan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas indica en su artículo sobre [mayúsculas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=BapzSnotjD6n0vZiTp):

> 4. **Uso de mayúscula inicial independientemente de la puntuación**. Se escriben con letra inicial mayúscula todos los nombres propios y también los comunes que, en un contexto dado o en virtud de determinados fenómenos (como, por ejemplo, la antonomasia), funcionan con valor de tales, es decir, cuando designan seres o realidades únicas y su función principal es la identificativa. En otras ocasiones, la mayúscula responde a otros factores, como la necesidad de distinguir entre sentidos diversos de una misma palabra (mayúscula diacrítica), o a razones expresivas o de respeto (mayúscula de respeto). Se escriben con inicial mayúscula las palabras siguientes:
>
> (...)
>
> 4.22. **Los nombres de marcas comerciales**. Las marcas comerciales son nombres propios, de forma que, utilizados específicamente para referirse a un producto de la marca, han de escribirse con mayúscula: Me gusta tanto el Cinzano como el Martini; Me he comprado un Seat; pero cuando estos nombres pasan a referirse no exclusivamente a un objeto de la marca en cuestión, sino a cualquier otro con características similares, se escriben con minúscula: Me aficioné al martini seco en mis años de estudiante (al vermú seco, de cualquier marca).

Por tanto, si *La Casa del Pan* es un nombre registrado, lo correcto es mantener el uso de mayúsculas:

> Bienvenido a La Casa del Pan

Sin embargo, debo añadir (y gracias, Carlos Alejo, por mencionarlo en los comentarios) el formato de tal nombre no suena demasiado español sino una copia del que se usa en inglés. Para esos casos, el mismo artículo indica:

> 4.17. La primera palabra del título de cualquier obra de creación (libros, películas, cuadros, esculturas, piezas musicales, programas de radio o televisión, etc.); el resto de las palabras que lo componen, salvo que se trate de nombres propios, deben escribirse con minúscula (...).

No es el mismo caso (aquí hablamos de una empresa y no de una obra de creación), pero creo que podemos tomar el consejo y usar el nombre comercial *La casa del pan* sin más mayúsculas que la inicial. Solamente añadiría alguna si se refiriera a algún sustantivo personal: *La casa del pan de Manolita* o *La casa del pan de Lepe*.

Comment: una pregunta, entonces si hay que poner mayúsculas, no sería La Casa Del Pan? digo, Del en vez de del

Comment: @Iria se trata de un nombre registrado, luego sigue las mayúsculas que decidió comercialmente. Si no fuera marca, solamente se pondría mayúscula en la primera

Comment: ¿Algún comentario sobre el voto negativo que me han cascado?

Answer (score 5):

> Además de la primera, se escriben con mayúscula inicial todas las palabras significativas que forman parte del nombre de establecimientos comerciales, culturales o recreativos, como bares, restaurantes, cafeterías, hoteles, cines, teatros, etc.: *(bar) Miraflores; (marisquería) La Perla; (grandes almacenes) El Corte Inglés; restaurante La Vaca Argentina; Almacenes Arias; (mercería) El Botón de Oro; (teatro) Nuevo Apolo; (cine) Avenida; (hotel) Villamagna*, etc.
>
> <sub>*Ortografía de la lengua española*, 2010. [Página 486](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hMCJZxSCKCYKaKhl).</sub>

Es decir, la forma correcta es La Casa del Pan, en redonda (no cursiva), con mayúscula en cada palabra significativa.

Answer (score 2):

Quería comentar que la RAE, en su propia web, escribe:

> Congreso Internacional de la Lengua Española, Real Academia Española, Casa Museo...

sin preocuparse por si es una influencia del inglés.

Tal vez pueda entenderse como ese concepto tan resbaladizo de la "mayúscula de respeto". Por lo tanto creo que si un negocio o marca por una cuestión estética o de costumbre, o de "respeto", quiere usar mayúscula en todas las palabras principales de su nombre, debería hacerlo sin preocupación. Así, apoyo la moción de La Casa del Pan.

Hay  empresas muy tradicionales y "respetadas" en mi país cuyas webs oficiales siguen este modelo: La Serenísima, El Amanecer, Nuevo Amanecer, etc.

<sub>Saludos y gracias a todos por este interesante intercambio.</sub>