# ¿Es correcto que el nombre de una empresa se escriba en mayúsculas, por ejemplo? MADIN LOSTE

Tags: ortografía

¿Es correcto que el nombre de una empresa se escriba en mayúsculas, por ejemplo? MAGÍN COSTE

Comment: No hay ninguna regla. Cada empresa, sociedad u asociacion utiliza lo que le da la gana.

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres de empresa, como marcas que son, no siguen las reglas de ortografía habituales e incluso [la Fundéu recomienda](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Marca) que se mantengan, en lo posible, los diacríticos que puedan contener, incluso cuando estos diacríticos no sean propios del español.

En España tenemos alguna marca que alterna mayúsculas y minúsculas de una forma totalmente impropia de nuestra lengua, como, por ejemplo, CaixaBank. Sin embargo, al escribir en español usaríamos esta grafía, como en [este titular](https://elpais.com/economia/2023-03-31/caixabank-reivindica-la-fortaleza-de-la-banca-espanola-ante-la-crisis-del-silicon-valley-bank.html) reciente del diario El País:

> CaixaBank urge a completar la unión bancaria europea

Otra cosa es la práctica habitual de usar las mayúsculas como resalte tipográfico. Aunque es bastante habitual verlo, sobre todo en documentos legales, [la RAE lo considera inadecuado](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1516750486954819586); sin embargo, *El libro del español correcto* del Instituto Cervantes dice al respecto:

> [...] puede que deseemos resaltar la palabra completa escribiéndola por entero con mayúsculas. En este último caso, solo debemos señalar que es aconsejable no abusar de este resalte, pues lejos de ayudar a llamar la atención sobre un elemento (o elementos) determinado, puede llegar a ensuciar el texto, esto es, puede llegar a dificultar su lectura.

Por tanto, suponiendo que el nombre comercial de la empresa sea Magín Coste, se podría escribir:

> El proveedor elegido es la empresa MAGÍN COSTE.

Pero siempre teniendo en cuenta que no debemos abusar de estas mayúsculas, porque distraen y hacen más difícil la lectura.

Answer (score 0):

#RAEconsultas Los nombres de organizaciones y empresas se escriben con mayúscula inicial en todos sus elementos significativos. Sobre los casos en que es válida la escritura de estas y otras expresiones enteramente en mayúsculas, v.

http://ow.ly/zku230nSQb9

[image]

Aunque en el nombre de las empresas no es correcto, en la practica se suele admitir por cuestiones de legibilidad o marketing si es la forma habitual que tiene la empresa de presentarse, **aunque lo más común es escribir el nombre de la empresa con la primera letra mayúscula y el resto en minúscula**. Ejem. Magín Coste.

Sin embargo, hay algunas empresas que eligen utilizar su nombre completo en mayúsculas como parte de su imagen de marca o estrategia de marketing. En estos casos, el nombre de la empresa puede escribirse MAGÍN COSTE.

En cualquier caso, lo importante es seguir la forma en que la empresa se presenta así misma y seguir en este caso las convenciones establecidas por la misma en cuanto a la escritura de su nombre, aunque no sea lo ideal.

---

#RAEconsultas Los nombres de establecimientos comerciales y recreativos se escriben con mayúscula inicial en todos sus elementos significativos y en redonda: «Fuimos al bar De Madrid al Cielo». V. el § 4.2.3.1.2 en

http://ow.ly/toFo30qY0EM.

[image]

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas

Answer (score 0):

No es correcto.

Los nombres de las empresas, como cualquier otro sustantivo propio, deben escribirse con mayúscula inicial en cada palabra (excepto las preposiciones y conjunciones, si las hay).

Si el nombre es una sigla (especialmente si debe deletrearse al pronunciarla) todas las letras son mayúsculas.

Otra cosa es que, por motivos estéticos, se desee escribir todo con mayúscula. En este caso está permitido y es lo más habitual. Por ejemplo en logotipos, carteles o títulos.

---

Como veo que no me creen, pueden ver esta otra pregunta [Uso de mayúsculas en nombres de negocios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18581/6915), o leer lo que dice el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas), específicamente los puntos 4.14 y 4.22.

Comment: No es verdad. Imediatamente, me vino: PEMEX.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Los nombres comerciales no siguen las normas ortotipográficas habituales. Por ejemplo, ninguna palabra puede empezar por minúscula y luego seguir con mayúscula; sin embargo, la forma correcta de escribir iPhone es así, porque es un nombre comercial y su dueño ha decidido que se escriba de esta forma.

Comment: @Gorpik De acuerdo en que es discutible, pero ten en cuenta que iPhone no es el nombre de una empresa ni está en español.

Comment: @Lambie Con respecto a Pemex, el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/may%C3%BAsculas) dice: "Se escriben enteramente en mayúscula las siglas y algunos acrónimos: _ISBN, OTI, ONG_. Se escriben en minúscula, en cambio, los acrónimos que el uso ha convertido en sustantivos comunes: _láser, radar, uvi_. Cuando los acrónimos son nombres propios y tienen más de cuatro letras, solo se escribe en mayúscula la inicial: _Unicef, Unesco_."

Comment: Petróleos Mexicanos (PEMEX) es una empresa estatal productora, transportista, refinadora y comercializadora de petróleo y gas natural mexicana. Wikipedia Es verdad que iPhone no es una. Otro ejemplo, mira todos estos bancos españolesL https://www.cnmv.es/portal/Consultas/ListadoEntidad.aspx?id=1&tipoent=7 :)

Comment: @Lambie Parece que estamos hablando de cosas diferentes. Ahora mismo estoy mirando mi cédula de identidad chilena que dice "RODRIGO", todo con mayúsculas. Una cosa es el nombre, y otra cosa es que, por énfasis o estética, a veces se opte por escribirlo con la tipografía que te de la gana.

Comment: Rodrigo: Todo eso nada tiene que ver con diccionarios. Tiene a ver con el estilo que le cae bien a la empresa. Estoy de acuedro con Gorpik.

Comment: @Rodrigo iPhone no está en español ni en ningún idioma: es un nombre comercial. Que sea de una empresa o de un producto es irrelevante.